# Auth0 api returning 401 www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" in .net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I am using auth0 with .net core web api, below are my configuration.

1. In my ConfigureServices() I have

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
       options.Authority = "https://xxxxxxx.auth0.com/";
       options.Audience = "https://localhost:5001";
   });
   ```
2. In my Configure() method I have

   ```
   // 2. Enable authentication middleware
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseMvc();
   ```

And finally in my HomeController.cs

```
    [HttpGet("private")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Private()
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
        });
    }
```

And when I try to access the endpoint, with the right access token, using postman or my react app I am getting 401 unauthorized or `www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"`

[image]

I followed the documentation for examples, cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Please advice.

Comment: How do you get the access token ?

Comment: How did you resolve the issue? I am having same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the scheme you use explicitly:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

instead of

```
[Authorize]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using this strategy in Postman:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/#bearer-token

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with configuration of token validation

```
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://xxxxxxx.auth0.com/",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:5001",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourSecretKey)),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});
```